# Sync Gazebo and Rviz

Tags: gazebo, rviz, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm very new to ROS. I just want to know, in this tutorial, for hydro turtlebot, wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/hydro/Explore%20the%20Gazebo%20world, where we have the 3D view in Gazebo while having the robot's view, how can I achieve that? Can someone tell me how can I have this kind of synchronization please?

In addition, can I also have a synchronized 2D overlooking map of the building of the world we have in Gazebo, such that the location of the robot changes accordingly while we move the robot in Gazebo?

Thanks so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173459/sync-gazebo-and-rviz/) by [JJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/18839/jj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-06-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/18839/jj/) on 2014-06-11**:
My Karma is not enough to add links. The link above should have http:// before it =) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi JJ, not sure if I understand your question, it sounds like you managed to launch Gazebo and Rviz simultaneously but you couldn't get Rviz to display what you wanted. If you simply launched rviz with the default configuration and nothing is shown except for the grid, you need to add display items in Rviz and link them to the appropriate topics/transforms which contain what you want to display.

I strongly suggest you go through the first rviz tutorial here, or at the very least through section 5 "viewing the markers" : wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes

As for the 2d overlooking map, once you have set up your display items, you can always change the view type in the rviz Views pane to "TopDownOrtho".

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2014-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/18839/jj/) on 2014-06-12**:
Thanks for answering my questions. It's very helpful. In addition, um, how do I make the robot model in Rviz move?

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2014-06-13**:
If you have added a 'RobotModel' display in the Displays pane, I guess you only need to edit its "Robot Description" parameter. Not sure what is the specific name for the turtlebot though, try "robot_description" maybe? It should be listed among the parameters when you type "rosparam list".